# React-native and Redux healthy way to call actions on props change

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I've been using react-native with redux for a while, and the way i learn to call actions when something change on prop is using the componentWillReceiveProps, but when I use it I need to pass between if's and some times it goes to the wrong if, then I need to add more stuff to prevent it.

Here's an example I have done. I know this is not the best way to do it, but it is what I could think of.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
    if(Object.keys(newProps.selected_product).length > 0) {
        if(Object.keys(this.props.current_location).length > 0 || Object.keys(newProps.current_location).length > 0) {
            this._handleNextPage(2);
            this.props.verifyProductById(newProps.selected_product, newProps.current_location, this.props.token);
        } else {
            this.props.statusScanner(false);
            this._handleNextPage(1);
        }
    } else if(Object.keys(newProps.historic_product_confirm).length > 0) {
        if(newProps.historic_product_confirm.location._id == newProps.current_location._id)
            this.props.handleModalConfirmPrice(!this.props.modal_confirmPrice_status)
    } else if(newProps.scanResult != "") {
        this.props.statusScanner(false);
        if(Object.keys(newProps.current_location).length > 0) {
            this._handleNextPage(2);
        } else {
            this._handleNextPage(1);
        }
    } else {
        this._handleNextPage(0);
    }
}
```

What I need is a healthy way to call my actions when the props change.

Edit: 
Here i have the full OfferScene and an action file example:

OfferScene:
https://gist.github.com/macanhajc/0ac98bbd2974d2f6fac96d9e30fd0642

UtilityActions: 
https://gist.github.com/macanhajc/f10960a8254b7659457f8a09c848c8cf

Comment: You must have actions which are resulting in change in these props like selected_product, historic_product_confirm, scanResult etc.. You can put logic from where the action is dispatched like user action or API result. But from above specified code above will be messy when your app/component scale.

Comment: just try to divide the problem as much as possible in multiple components this will help in cleaner and scalable code.

Comment: Can you post your sample `actions` or how you handle the api?

Comment: @Goldy I already do that, but on this case the code is from a scene, on that i need to change the currentPage to navigate between components and that is controled by an scrollview.

Comment: @PritishVaidya I have posted the full scene and an action file now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in another answer, `componentWillReceiveProps` is being phased out, so I would aim for trying to eliminate it where possible. You'll be future-proofing your code and keeping your component logic more declarative and easy to reason about. As someone who has been responsible for (and been frustrated by) lifecycle method abuse like this, here are some things that have helped me.

Remember that when using `redux-thunk`, along with passing `dispatch` as the first argument, you can also pass `getState` as the second. This allows you to access state values in your action logic instead of bringing them into your component's props and adding clutter. Something like:

```
export const ExampleAction = update =>
  (dispatch, getState) => {
    const { exampleBool } = getState().ExampleReducer

    if (exampleBool) {
      dispatch({
        type: 'UPDATE_EXAMPLE_STATE',
        update
      })
    }
  }
```

Using async/await in action logic can be a lifesaver when your action depends upon fetched results from an API call:

```
export const ExampleAction = () =>
  async (dispatch, getState) => {
    const { valueToCheck } = getState().ExampleReducer
        , result = await someAPICall(valueToCheck)
                   .catch(e => console.log(e))

    if (result.length > 0) {
      dispatch({
        type: 'UPDATE_EXAMPLE_STATE',
        update: result
      })
    }
  }
```

For cases where your component's rendering behavior depends upon certain state values after your state has been updated, I highly recommend [reselect](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect). A very basic example would be something like:

**component.js**

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { shouldDisplayItems } from '../selectors'
import MyListviewComponent from './myListview'

class ItemList extends Component {
  render() {
    const { shouldDisplayItems, items } = this.props

    return (
      <>
        {shouldDisplayItems && <MyListviewComponent items={items} />}
      </>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ ListItems }) => shouldDisplayItems(ListItems)

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ItemList)
```

**selectors.js:**

(Assuming your ListItems reducer has the params `items` and `visibilityFilter`)

```
import { createSelector } from 'reselect'

export const shouldDisplayItems = createSelector(
  [state => state],
  ({ items, visibilityFilter }) => {
    return {
      shouldDisplayItems: visibilityFilter && items.length > 0,
      items
    }
  }
)
```

I should mention that another option would be using [higher-order components](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html), but it can be tricky to use this approach before having a good grasp on how to keep too much imperative logic out of your components (I learned this the hard way).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @AnuragChutani and @Goldy in terms of clarity of the code; break it down some more into more components or functions.

Now after some review of your componentWillReceiveProps function, it is definitely not specific enough to narrow down exactly which prop changes. If any connected redux variable changes, the componentWillReceiveProps function will be invoked each time.

So e.g. if 'token' or 'selected_product' updates, componentWillReceiveProps will be triggered, even though you did not want it to trigger for token updates.

You can use a comparison for a specific variable update in the props.
E.g Using lodash

```
if(!_.isEqual( nextProps.selected_product, this.props.selected_product ))
// if props are different/updated, do something
```

Secondly, you can call actions/callbacks in your actions to narrow down navigation.
E.g.

```
takePicture = (camera, options){
  ...
  //on success
  dispatch(handleModalConfirmPrice())
  ...
}}
```